# Couldn't see the "Sharing Sets" section in the Community --> Settings

Tags: administration, sharing, customer-portal, customer-community

We are configuring a new org (enterprise edition). I need to create a Sharing set for our Customer Community Plus Login users to access the records. I couldn't find the SHARING SETS section in Build | Customize | Communities | Settings. Now, every customer user can view all the cases in the Community.

[image]

In our old Org, I've configured a Sharing set for the Portal users in Build | Customize | Customer Portal | Settings. Similarly for Communities, to make sure I'm in the right track, I've referred the navigation in the below links:

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/networks_setting_light_users.htm

http://blog.edlconsulting.com/salesforce-com/crm/sharing-records-in-a-salesforce-com-customer-community/

I'm a System Admin. Do we have to enable/select any checkbox for viewing/using this Sharing set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&language=en_US

The access mapping on a Sharing Set for Portal/Community is available for these profiles:

- Authenticated Website
- Customer Community User
- Customer Community Login User
- High Volume Customer Portal
- High Volume Portal
- Overage Authenticated Website User
- Overage High Volume Customer Portal User

Since Customer Community Plus Login license is not in this list, obviously it doesn't have the Sharing set in the Settings to grant access to users in the community.