# Customer Portal Plus user's access to custom object's records

Tags: community, sharing, customer-portal, customer-community

I would like to share with my community users records of particular custom object.
Users use Customer Portal Plus licenses.

I would like situation where every user can view every record of this custom object, that have Lookup to user's Account.

Is this possible?
I think that sharing sets would be the thing I need, but they aren't available for Customer Portal Plus licenses:
[Couldn't see the “Sharing Sets” section in the Community --> Settings](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83047/couldnt-see-the-sharing-sets-section-in-the-community-settings)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Goto Setup -> Security -> Sharing Settings and enable the external sharing model.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you've pointed to is incorrect and here's why. The Customer Community Plus license is an "enhanced" version of the Customer Community license. It's totally counter-intuitive that it wouldn't have the same features as a standard Customer Community license. See [Salesforce Communities Licenses](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html) for a comparison.

That having been said, all one needs to do is "clone" their Customer Community Plus license and add additional permissions to it. Once you clone your license, you can add the permissions you're speaking of or any other kind of permission set that you'd like.

Additionally, I'm showing in my Dev Org that the default settings for Accounts in a Community Plus User profile is Read, Create and Edit for Accounts. You might want to restrict that if you haven't already. Clearly it surpasses the requirements for your custom object and allows the access you're speaking of.

That having been said, in your post, you've used the term "Customer Portal Plus" license. Is this a "Portal" or a "Community"? I'm not aware of a *Customer Portal Plus License*, only a *Customer Community Plus License*. Is this perhaps some kind of upgraded portal user license that your org has negotiated with Salesforce or have you inadvertently used an incorrect term?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, licenses are named "Customer Community Plus Login".

Still, I have same problem as in linked questions, I don't see "Sharing sets" related list anywhere.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Have you enabled [External Organization-Wide Default Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_owd_external_setting.htm) and 2. are you using [Enhanced profile user interface or original](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_profiles_custom_perms.htm)? You should be able to add perms to profiles.

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Enhanced.
When I set Organization Wide Defaults to public I can see these records. But I'm not really happy with that solution. I would prefer setting OWD to private and extend user's access by Sharing set.

Comment: While you may have preferred having the option to use a sharing set, did this route produce the same results for you?

Comment: It depends, on how you look at it: Yes it worked, no I cannot leave this object OWD set to public.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was trying to learn. Is the OWD set to public internal, external or both? Are you using a custom profile for your community plus users? I recommend creating a custom profile to use for your external users, once you do, you'll be able to add permissions via the enhanced profile editor. You "should" also  be able to create a new sharing group for users with that custom profile too. It just may not appear in the external dialogue where you're expecting it to be. Use the normal sharing group editor instead if necessary.

Comment: OWD is set to private for both internal and external. Yes I'm using custom profile for my external users. Yes I've added permissions for this profile. Still, I don't think I can accomplish the same functionality as Sharing sets with profile / groups(I mean sharing based on having the same Account lookup on user and custom object). I think i will need to go with custom triggers which will add Apex Sharing for the external users.

Comment: Apex sharing isn't available for communities. That may be part of the disconnect we've been having here. Record by record sharing is very difficult to accomplish with communities.

Comment: That's rather strange, because yesterday I have successfully created trigger on our dev sandbox, that creates __share objects for my custom objects, and it works when my user logs in via community.

Comment: Unless its a newly enabled feature that I missed in the SU15 release notes, Apex sharing has never been available for communities. Glad to hear the way you've implemented it is working for you.

Comment: I also thought that it won't work, but it works despite the information in documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm . Probably Apex Sharing works for Plus and community partner licenses.

Comment: That's a new one to me. Thanks for sharing that. No pun intended. ;) I believe it does work for Partner Users as they have Roles assigned to them. Would need to double check that one first though. Has been a while since I've looked at those docs. I'm not aware of Community Plus users having Roles. Will need to look into that one further. Anything unique about the Groups you used that perhaps allowed it to happen?